# Why do I have an issue with onClick Event in Datatable JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, datatable

So, I have a datatable js and its script goes something like

```
<script>
      var table;
      var init = 0;
      $(document).ready(function () {

          if (init == 0) {
              table = $('#example').DataTable({
                  columnDefs: [{
                      orderable: false,
                      className: 'select-checkbox',
                      targets: 0
                  }, {
                      "targets": [2],
                      "visible": false,
                      "searchable": false
                  }],
                  select: {
                      style: 'os',
                      selector: 'td:first-child'
                  },
                  order: [
                      [1, 'asc']
                  ]
              });
              init = 1;
          }
      })

      $('#btnSelectedRows').on('click', function () {
          alert('here');
              var tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();
              var tmpData;
              $.each(tblData, function (i, val) {
                  tmpData = tblData[i];
                  alert(tmpData);

              });
                document.location.href = "https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42290/getting-the-checked-rows-in-datatables";
          })



  </script>
```

now here, when I am calling the onclick event is not triggered, while on other hand if I move it under ready() it will get invoked. This problem I am facing when I create a new html however, it works perfect in JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/q67L1a9a/)

Comment: `while on other hand if I move it under ready() it will get invoked` Try doing just that, then. Sounds like you're trying to select the element before it's been parsed in the HTML. Or, even better, write your script in a separate file and give its tag the `defer` attribute.

Comment: @CertainPerformance if I do that the document.location.href wont work.

Comment: What do you mean `wont work`? Seems to work properly for me when I wrap everything in the `ready`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It just would redirect, I don't know if its because of datatable.js or some other issue, i tired it for good 2 days before posting.

Comment: The whole point of assigning to `location.href` is to redirect. If you don't want to redirect after all, just remove that line? Please explain what the problem is

Comment: Once I click the button, it will show me the selected information (which it does if I put in ready()) and then it should redirect, which it doesn't redirect. I saw a post on fiddle where that guy had put outside the ready() and it worked perfectly for him including the redirect part, the same is not happening for me

Comment: That's exactly how it seems to behave for me. If a row is selected, it `alert`s the row information, and then redirects. Can't reproduce the problem, sorry

Comment: Strange I am not able to redirect, can you please share html of fiddle if possible, @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

There seem few problems with the code:

1) The variable `table` is defined globally but its value being assigned inside `$(document).ready` so I believe the reference to `table` variable outside may not work.

2) The jquery you wrote in the other function is doing actions on the DOM elements which were not present when the page rendered. So you should use jQuery event delegation. To do so: just change your code like:

```
<script>
      var table;
      var init = 0;
      $(document).ready(function () {

          if (init == 0) {
              table = $('#example').DataTable({
                  columnDefs: [{
                      orderable: false,
                      className: 'select-checkbox',
                      targets: 0
                  }, {
                      "targets": [2],
                      "visible": false,
                      "searchable": false
                  }],
                  select: {
                      style: 'os',
                      selector: 'td:first-child'
                  },
                  order: [
                      [1, 'asc']
                  ]
              });
              init = 1;
          }

      $(document).on('click', '#btnSelectedRows', function () {
          alert('here');
              var tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();
              var tmpData;
              $.each(tblData, function (i, val) {
                  tmpData = tblData[i];
                  alert(tmpData);

              });
                document.location.href = "https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42290/getting-the-checked-rows-in-datatables";
          });
      });

  </script>
```

Comment: Thankyou @Himanshu Upadhyay for the solution, but the same code worked on my other computer :) But thanks for sharing